# Read HBase data into Spark via Apache Phoenix

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, configuration, hbase, apache-phoenix

Being a noob to working with Spark, Phoenix and HBase, was a trying a few examples, as listed out [here](https://blogs.apache.org/phoenix/entry/spark_integration_in_apache_phoenix) and [here](https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html).

Created the data as per the example for "us_population" [here](https://phoenix.apache.org/Phoenix-in-15-minutes-or-less.html).

However, on trying to query the Table thus created in Phoenix / HBase, via Spark, I get the following error -

```
scala> val rdd = sc.phoenixTableAsRDD("us_population", Seq("CITY", "STATE", "POPULATION"), zkUrl = Some("random_aws.internal:2181"))
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/phoenix/jdbc/PhoenixDriver
  at org.apache.phoenix.spark.PhoenixRDD.<init>(PhoenixRDD.scala:40)
  at 
org.apache.phoenix.spark.SparkContextFunctions.phoenixTableAsRDD(SparkContextFunctions.scala:39)
  ... 52 elided
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
  ... 54 more
```

Unsure why this error is popping up. Any help for the same would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. I load Spark with the following command -

```
 spark-shell --jars /usr/lib/phoenix/phoenix-spark-4.9.0-HBase-1.2.jar
```

Am attempting this on a tiny AWS EMR cluster of 1 Master and 1 Name Node (both are R4.xlarge with 20GB SSD external storage)

Answer (score 2):

The exception you got due to class org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver missing in the spark executors classpath.

Try to add phoenix-core-4.9.0-HBase-1.2.jar when you start spark-shell.

```
spark-shell --jars /usr/lib/phoenix/phoenix-spark-4.9.0-HBase-1.2.jar,/usr/lib/phoenix/phoenix-core-4.9.0-HBase-1.2.jar
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidGreenshtein.
Slight change in the result, on running your solution - it gives a new error:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration at org.apache.phoenix.spark.PhoenixRDD.getPhoenixConfiguration(PhoenixRDD.scala:75)`

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration`

Comment: phoenix-spark jar has additional compile dependencies - hbase-client, hadoop-common, hadoop-client you can see them [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-spark/4.9.0-HBase-1.2). You can add all of them to the list of jars with --jars parameter or build an uber jar of phoenix-spark contains all dependencies having compile scope.